# How can I create a "forEach" that returns an object that is a receiver to the consuming function?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to do something like this in a long chain of "stream" operations.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    "test1, test2, test3".split(", ")
            .toCustomString(StringBuilder(), StringBuilder::append)
}

fun <T, R>Iterable<T>.toCustomString(obj: R, thing: R.(T) -> Unit): R {
    this.forEach {
        obj.thing(it)
    }
    return obj
}
```

But this doesn't work it says none of the functions found for `StringBuilder::append` can't be applied here. Is there a way I can make something like this work?

Comment: Kotlin has something called [Extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) the receiver is the Object that the extension function is invoked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem to use a method reference in that case and it should work perfectly.

Just ensure you use kotlin class `StringBuilder` an change this:

`fun <T, R>Iterable<T>.toCustomString(obj: R, thing: R.(T) -> Unit)`

by this one:

`fun <T, R>Iterable<T>.toCustomString(obj: R, thing: R.(T) -> R)`

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I feel like I understand the background why it dosen't work. I've now changed the signature of the function to `R.(T) -> Any?` so that it works with the `StringBuilder::append` aswell as a anonym function like `{append(it)}`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use a method reference with a different signature for a receiver function. You can make it work with supplying a lambda instead. Or as other answers point out, changing the signature of your receiver function.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    "test1, test2, test3".split(", ")
            .toCustomString(StringBuilder(), { item -> append(item) })
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm an idiot and thought that didn't work because of another error in my code. (I'll accept your answer when I can!)

Comment: There's no issue at all to use a method reference like `StringBuilder::append` as I pointed out in my answer. In fact, it's a clearer way to do that for this particular case.

Comment: Correct, what the answer is missing that the signatures of functions don't match.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `StringBuilder::append` as a function reference, `thing` should have type `R.(T) -> R` instead of `R.(T) -> Unit` because  `StringBuilder.append(String)` will return `StringBuilder`. However, since `toCustomString` does not handle the return value from `StringBuilder.append`, what @Marko suggested is more appropriate.

FYR, here is an alternative way to do it without an extra extension function:

```
val customString = StringBuilder().apply {
    "test1, test2, test3"
            .split(", ")
            .forEach { this.append(it) }
}
```

Comment: Yeap, `R.(T) -> R` fix is what I answered in my answer before. However I don't understand your second part of the answer. `toCustomString` extension method does what it does, it's up to the caller to handle the result or not, but it makes sense. Another thing is what he does in his dummy `main` test function, which should make sense and it doesn't. In a real app use that extension could be helpful and IMHO the function reference is the clearer way to do that. No need to reinvent the wheel if the `fun` it's already implemented.

Comment: What I mean is that the return value from `obj.thing(it)` is not handled. So, I suppose that `thing()` is a mutating function. Due to this, I think `R.(T) -> Unit` is more appropriate because most of the mutating function have return type `Unit` instead of the receiver type.